# How to get the greatest element of a GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

As you can see I would like to get the latest purchase order for each SKU.

## Sample Data

I have this data set,

```
CREATE TABLE PurchaseOrders (
        id            int  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        sku           varchar(6),
        purchase_date date
);


INSERT INTO PurchaseOrders VALUES
    ( 1, 'ABC123', '2017-12-23' ),
    ( 2, 'ABC123', '2016-11-11' ),
    ( 3, 'DEF456', '2011-01-03' ),
    ( 4, 'DEF456', '2011-10-21' ),
    ( 5, 'GHI789', '2017-01-23' ),
    ( 6, 'GHI789', '2017-11-21' );
```

## Desired Result

```
1 | ABC123 | 2017-12-23
4 | DEF456 | 2011-10-21
6 | GHI789 | 2017-11-21
```

Comment: So you want the *maximum* purchase date for each SKU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably easiest to do with a join against a derived table:

```
select a.* 
from PurchaseOrders as a 
join ( 
    select sku, max(date) as date
    from PurchaseOrders
    group by sku
) as b 
   on a.sku = b.sku 
   and a.date = b.date;
```

The derived table b contains the max dt for each sku. To get the id we join that against the original table.

As Evan Carroll points out you can shorten this a bit since the name of the join attributes is the same for both left and right operand:

```
select a.* 
from PurchaseOrders as a 
join ( 
    select sku, max(date) as date
    from PurchaseOrders
    group by sku
) as b 
   using (sku, date);
```

Comment: Could use `USING (sku, dt)` here to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break your problem into two part one would be getting the latest orders for each group that can very much be found by the following query:

```
select sku,max([date]) as OrderDate from PurchaseOrders
group by sku
```

It will yield the following results:

```
ABC123 | 2017-12-23
DEF456 | 2011-10-21
GHI789 | 2017-11-21
```

Next what you want is the id for these orders that can be done using the following query:

```
select * from PurchaseOrders a,(
    select sku,max([date]) as OrderDate from PurchaseOrders
    group by sku

) as b
where a.sku in(b.sku) and a.[date] in (b.OrderDate)
order by id
```

This will yield your final result as:

```
1 | ABC123 | 2017-12-23
4 | DEF456 | 2011-10-21
6 | GHI789 | 2017-11-21
```

Hope this is the answer you are looking for :).

Answer (score 1):

Although not quite yet stable (GA), MySQL 8.0+ (and MariaDB 10.2 - stable (GA)) supports CTEs and window functions, so we can do:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT id, sku, purchase_date, RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY purchase_date DESC
  ) AS rnk 
  FROM PurchaseOrders
) 
SELECT r.id, r.sku, r.purchase_date 
FROM ranked r 
WHERE r.rnk=1
ORDER BY r.id;
```

I don't know if this is likely, but if we imagine an additional record, essentially a duplicate of the data in record with id 6:

```
INSERT INTO PurchaseOrders (id, sku, purchase_date) VALUES (7, 'GHI789', '2017-11-21');
```

... then this new record will be displayed as well. If you want to avoid that, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK()`.

With the CTE + window function approach it's also trivial to get, let's say, the second most recent purchase order per sku, or the two most recent ones, and so forth, by modifying the `WHERE r.rnk=1` clause.

Answer (score -2):

I hope it will help you.

```
SELECT max(date) AS date, sku
FROM PurchaseOrders
GROUP BY sku;
```

Comment: The problem with this is you're not getting the `ID`.